# Vue.js 2 click events working on desktop however not on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, mobile, vuejs2

I have several JS files containing vue.js 2 code and components, and I have added a few features using this on to a web page. Everything seems to be working fine on desktop, however not on mobile browsers (specifically Safari and Chrome). Specifically, click events aren't working. Other vue.js functions work fine, but not clicks.

I've tried a few different approaches, and have tried to log the problem out in chrome://inspect on mobile, however I do not get any error messages/logs. The issue is present on all elements, regardless of whether a tag elements or simply divs with click handlers, if the element has v-on:click or @click, then these events are not fired on mobile.

There is a lot of code, so difficult to pick one specific example. But here is one:

```
import Vue from 'vue';



const customiseProductFinishing = Vue.component('customise-product-finishing', {

  data: function () {
    return {
      breadcrumbValue: 0,
      activeIndex: 0,
    }
  },


  methods: {
    isActive: function(that) {
      console.log('that', that);
      return 'active';
    },

    handleBreadcrumbClick(num) {
      this.breadcrumbValue = num;
      this.activeIndex = num;
    }
  },

  template: `
    <div class="customise-form__card" id="customise-card-second-stage">
        <ul class="progress-breadcrumbs">
          <li v-on:click="handleBreadcrumbClick(0)" class="progress-breadcrumbs__item" :class="{ 'active': activeIndex === 0 }">Size</li>
          <li v-on:click="handleBreadcrumbClick(1)" class="progress-breadcrumbs__item" :class="{ 'active': activeIndex === 1 }">Band</li>
          <li v-on:click="handleBreadcrumbClick(2)" class="progress-breadcrumbs__item" :class="{ 'active': activeIndex === 2 }">Ring Size</li>
          <li v-on:click="handleBreadcrumbClick(3)" class="progress-breadcrumbs__item" :class="{ 'active': activeIndex === 3 }">Engraving</li>
          <li v-on:click="handleBreadcrumbClick(4)" class="progress-breadcrumbs__item" :class="{ 'active': activeIndex === 4 }">Embossing</li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
  `
});

export default customiseProductFinishing;
```

I just need my existing functionality that's been built around the click handlers to work on mobile devices. I'm not sure what the best and quickest solution would be. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend to debug that from scratch. First of all check if there is click event on the body or tag (via document.addEventListener() with vanilla js). Maybe `@click.native` will work?

Comment: Can you create a https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: I've managed to debug a little further and have seen that when the page loads on mobile, if I don't scroll at all and just click, then the click events fire. As soon as I scroll just the slightest amount, then click events do not fire...